# Highcharts custom tooltip positioner

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart with more than one series and shared tooltips. The point object in the `positioner(labelWidth, labelHeight, point)` callback function only contains the leftmost point within the hovered category. I'd like to position the tooltip above the *highest* bar within that category. If the leftmost bar is smaller than any of the other bars, then the tooltip overlays these higher bars.

Is there any way to get all points within the hovered category instead of only the leftmost one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could loop over `hoverPoints` and find the one that you need.

```
positioner: function(w, h) {
  var chart = this.chart,
    hoverPoints = chart.hoverPoints,
    len = hoverPoints.length,
    topPoint = hoverPoints[0],
    x,
    y;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (hoverPoints[i].y > topPoint.y) {
      topPoint = hoverPoints[i];
    }
  }

  x = topPoint.barX + chart.plotLeft + topPoint.pointWidth / 2 - w / 2;
  y = topPoint.plotY + chart.plotTop - h;

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
},
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5f7558ro/1/