# How to make the position of shared tooltip be above the points?

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I found a lot of answers for this question, but no one fit mine.
So, we can see that regular tooltip is located above the point, like in this picture:
[image]

And when I change this example to use `shared:true`, the tooltip located in the left side:
[image]

Now I just want that shared tooltip will be located above the 2 points(in the example).
I know that I need to add code in the property `positioner`, but I cant figure out the math. more than that, if `outside: true` than I absolutely can't understand the math.

So, to conclude, how to make the position in shared tooltip to be above the points?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's really annoying task!
So I give a solution for `shared tooltip` and `outside: true`.
So first problem was to understand the coordinates system.
When `outside: true` we work relative to `window`, and when `outside: false` we work relative to `chart`.

Second, you can see if you put a log, that point values are always relative to chart, so what to do when we do `outside: true`?

Here the code which worked for me:

```js
  outside: true,
  positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
    const chart = this.chart;
    const chartPosition = chart.pointer.getChartPosition();
    const hoverPoints = chart.hoverPoints;
    const highestPoint = [...hoverPoints].sort((a, b) => a.plotY - b.plotY)[0];
    const middlePoint = hoverPoints[Math.floor(hoverPoints.length / 2)];

    return {
      x:
        chartPosition.left +
        middlePoint.barX +
        chart.plotLeft +
        middlePoint.pointWidth / 2 -
        labelWidth / 2,
      y: chartPosition.top + highestPoint.plotY - labelHeight
    };
  },
```

I used a little the solutions from:

1. [How to position highcharts tooltip above chart with outside:true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594601/how-to-position-highcharts-tooltip-above-chart-with-outsidetrue)
2. [Highcharts custom tooltip positioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877255/highcharts-custom-tooltip-positioner)

To a little bit explain my solution, i share a picture:
[image]

Till now I'm not 100% understand what exactly each property say, but it's the way.

To investigate further, I suggest you to put a lot of console.logs on the properties, and also I used this code pasted to Console in devtools:

```
addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log(`x: ${event.clientX}, y: ${event.clientY}`);
})
```

It helped me to create a target, for example:
"The middle need to be in x:250 and y:300 because I clicked on the middle and got this values => let's play with the properties to get closer as I can!"